# How can I raise my opinion to a biased person without looking too offensive?

Tags: conversations, etiquette, parents

Personally, I am a 25 year old male who has just graduated with a Computer Science degree and currently a Software Engineer by profession.

Recently, my dad was very interested in numerology after consulting a numerology expert, and he keeps chatting about it with his other friends over phone calls while I’m working at home during my office hours, which disrupts the peaceful work environment I desire. One day, he comes by and tells me about how accurate this numerology expert is with his predictions, and that the expert accepts a huge sum of money from people(my dad included), to help them generate a unique 4 digit number “lifecode”, given their 8 digit birthday (DDMMYYYY format) with his “secret algorithm”, which is said to bring a huge positive change in fortune to the person who is aware of his own number.

He asked me whether I would be able to help him reverse engineer the algorithm, so that he could possibly know how the expert generated the numbers and maybe be able to do the same. He provided me with mappings of birthdays to their “lifecode” from 4 other customers he knows of.

Personally, I found the expert’s claim fishy, as it doesn’t sound convincing that 10^8 birthdays (Considering all number places) can map to a unique 10^4 lifecodes (Considering all number places). I have tried to raise my opinion to him, but the moment he heard the phrase “mathematically impossible” from me, he just shuts away any opportunity I have at explaining myself and changes the topic. I have that little tingling feeling of being unheard, but I have gotten used to it as this is not the first time he has closed the conversation about something which leads to a “mathematical argument”.

I have a feeling it’s because he deeply trusts his instincts over mine. In fact, he, now in his late 50s, was once an Electrical Engineer by profession for a significant part of his career and over the years of my upbringing, he is convinced that I am a narrow-minded person who is exceptionally weak in terms of what he perceives as common sense, like my inability to perform basic carpentry tasks competently, or do errands related to buying hardware. It could be that he has formed a very deep bias against me and is now refusing to accept any opinions from me, even if they do align with my current profession. I am quite confident of my line of thinking this time round, according to what he has described to me.

I have asked my friends what they will do if they encounter a close person doing something unusual, differing from the norm, and if they bothered informing that person and hearing their rationale behind their unusual behavior, to allow the person (or the confronting person) to get a sanity check on the situation, and allow the confronting person to let go of that “burning question”.

Most of them told me that they would just mind their own business and wait until the person approaches them for their opinion and that will be the best time to let them know about their differences in beliefs. For me, my situation is a little different as I stand to gain a peaceful work environment if I do convince the “unusual” person of his “unusual beliefs” and cause his future conversations about this topic to stop.

Would like to ask what is a good way to approach him to get his future conversations to stop without coming off as too offensive and dismissive of his beliefs, especially if there’s possibly an inherent bias against me.

Comment: This won’t help your interpersonal problem, but there are not 10^8 possible permutations of MMDDYYYY for currently living people. Granted there are about 36,525 for people 0-100 years old, so there will be duplicates of the 10^4 life codes.